# Keras and cross validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, cross-validation

I am currently trying train a regression network using keras.  To ensure I proper training I've want to train using crossvalidation.

The Problem is that it seems that keras don't have any functions supporting crossvalidation or do they?

The only solution I seemed to have found is to use scikit test_train_split and run a model.fit for  for each k fold manually.  Isn't there a already an integrated solutions for this, rather than manually doing it ?

Answer (score 2):

Nope... That seem to be the solution. (Of what I know of.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a scikit learn wrapper for Keras that will help you do this easily: https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/

I recommend reading Dr. Jason Brownlee's example: https://machinelearningmastery.com/regression-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library-python/

```
   def baseline_model():
        # create model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(13, input_dim=13, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
        # Compile model
        model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
        return model

estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=wider_model, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, Y, cv=kfold)
```

Comment: This only works for X being 2-dimensional, and not 3-dimensional such as for LSTM. [ref](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1711)